# How can I get more information about Servers under Recent Items?

Tags: macos, network, finder

There are a number of Servers under Recent Items. The usual trick of holding down on command does not reveal any other information.

Can more information be obtained from this list of recent connections?

e.g. last time they were used, what operations happened, other details perhaps[image: recent servers]

Comment: Perhaps if you included a screen capture of what you are talking about (add it to your question). I have *never* seen a server listed under recent items as those are usually things that are launched manually by the user, not automatically by the system.

Comment: By the way, you can take screenshots on Mac with ⌘-Shift-4 (fullscreen) or ⌘-Shift-3 (certain portion or application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few resources ([1](https://www.mac4n6.com/blog/2016/1/1/manual-analysis-of-nskeyedarchiver-formatted-plist-files-a-review-of-the-new-os-x-1011-recent-items), [2](http://michaellynn.github.io/2015/10/24/apples-bookmarkdata-exposed/), [3](https://blackbagtech.com/blog/2017/01/17/recent-items-in-macos-sierra/)) that describe how to get more information on Recent Servers (and other Recent Items). I'll summarize them here:

You can locate the RecentServers.plist or RecentServers.sfl in ~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/

To convert the plist file into a more human-readable format, use plutil:

```
plutil –p <plist_file> > <output_file_here>
```

I used json as the file extension, which you can open up in a text editor.

The information this file gives you is limited. There are no dates associated with the data. What I found useful was the URL for Key 16.

I believe this only works to macOS 10.13 and below. It seems that in 10.14 that the Recent Items files are now sfl2 files.